# VSCode marks PHP constructor property promotion as error

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-8

In VSCode, when trying to use constructor property promotion code is marked as error with red squigglies and when hovering over the modifier e.g., private the message says: ')' expected, '{' expected, '}' expected. There is also a read marking below the commas in the argument list  and the notice says: ';' expected. There is no problem running the code, and the version of php supports property promotion, so why do I get this marking and how can I get rid of it, it is driving me absolutely mad. I have tried using Intelephense (and then disabling the language feature as it says in the instructions). I also tried other extensions but still those ugly red markings when nothing is wrong.

I'm running php v8.2.9 on ubuntu.
I also have latest version of VSCode 1.81.1
I have updateded everything on the machine with apt
Including an image of an example of how it looks in VSCode.
[code showing errors in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNjPh.png)

The code that generates the errors on private and commas i constructor property list:

```
class UserWithPropertyPromotion
{
    public function __construct(private string $name,
                                private string $email)
    { 
        echo json_encode(["name" => $this->name,
                          "email" => $this->email ]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @DarkBee it's [a PHP8 feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion). The `PHP Intelliphense` VS Code extension seems to support this feature for me—no red squiggly underlines—so it's something that _should_ also work for OP.

Comment: @RickN - Thanks for the reading material. Reading through the docs, wouldn't that mean OP still has to declare the class properties, which aren't defined in the second screenshot?

Comment: @DarkBee the reason for not adding the code as code but as an image is that it is not the code that is the issue, it is the marking of the code as error that is the issue. According to all documentation I've read (e.g., https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8), using property promotion allows you to combine definition and variable assignment all into one syntax in the constructor parameter list and I think that is a nice feature to use, but I want to be able to use it without errors in VSCode.

Comment: The editor might be up to date, but the syntax highlighting plugin isn't.

Comment: @Sammitch, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "syntax highlighting plugin", do you refer to Intelephense, or otherwise what? I have installed the latest available version of Intelephense (1.9.5). For other languages and libraries I have no problem in VSCode, e.g., javascript, typescript, react and CSS correctly marks code with and without errors and is very helpful as I expect it to be. But for PHP I'm about to give up and go back to just using good old trustworthy gvim...